# SSL rewrite partially works. web.config error or nopcommerce issue?

Tags: ssl, https, web-config, nopcommerce, iis-10

I am using nopcommerce 2.60 where the settings of SSL are in Web.config 
.net version 4.6.2,
IIS 10

I had not been able to get shared SSL to work until now.
Yes, I know about the web.config settings "UseSSL" and "SharedSSL".

web.config first option are like these

```
<add key="UseSSL" value="true" />
    <add key="SharedSSLUrl" value="https://demo.site.com" />
    <add key="NonSharedSSLUrl" value="http://demo.site.com" />
```

After research I found one rules that partially works

1) Partially the Home page works but NOT all elements served from HTTPS
   Some elements insist in HTTP

but the admin page works fully in HTTPS.

```
<rule name="HTTPS Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
```

Is there any obvious problem that I do not see ?

Can you suggest a rule that could make the HTTPS to work in both Front Page and Backend?

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are serving mixed content (http over https), maybe your views are referring directly to some http content like this:

```
    <img src="http:..."
```

or

```
    <script src="...."
```

If your views are ok, maybe its a plugin doing this.

I suggest to inspect the html code of your website with a browser console, find wich element is served as http and then fix it.